# How do I prevent Chrome developer tools from closing when the current browser window closes?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to use the chrome developer tools to debug an issue I'm having with Twitter oauth.

When the oauth window appears, I open the developer tools to monitor the requests - but as soon as the oauth window closes the developer tools window is also closed. I'd like to be able to keep the developer tools window open so that I can inspect the requests made.

Is this possible?

Comment: FYI, I just filed a bug against Chromium about this: http://crbug.com/171447.

Comment: As of December 15, 2017,  crbug.com/171447 is fixed.

Comment: @tom_mai78101 how do I activate it?

Answer (score 124):

Not a perfect solution, but you can add breakpoints on the events `Window.close` and `unload` by turning on the checkboxes at:

```
Developer tools -> "Sources" tab -> Event Listener Breakpoints -> Window -> close
```

And

```
Event Listener Breakpoints -> Load -> unload
```

Try to mark both and see which one works best for you

Comment: Does someone know why this doesn't do the trick for me? The window still closes.

Comment: I think I am having the same issue.  It I have developer window open for my app but the oauth process is popping a new window and thus my break points are not there.  I see the developer window pop and close with the oauth window...sigh

Comment: This is amazing. The `Window -> close` checkbox does the trick for me. Note: this setting (sadly) doesn't persist across windows or sessions, so you have to go check the box in whatever window is going to close, before it closes.

Answer (score 30):

Another option is to manually add a breakpoint yourself. Open up your closes-too-quickly window, open up JS console, and:

```
window.addEventListener('unload', function() { debugger; })
```

But it all comes down to exactly what the window is doing, and when exactly you want to stop things, so experimenting with Event Listener Breakpoints in the Sources tab, as in @jfhfhf839's answer, is a good idea too.

In my case (debugging Google OAuth flow), neither `Window -> Close` nor `Load -> Unload` did the trick, but `Script > Script First Statement` was useful, though I had to resume execution a few times before I got to where I wanted.

Comment: For IE, you can use: 
`window.attachEvent("onunload",  function() { debugger; })`

Answer (score 5):

Try using [remote debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging). In this case Developer Tools will be opened in a separate browser tab that won't be closed automatically.

To do this you will need to open two instances of Chrome:

- one with a custom [remote-debugging-port](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69368719/288906), where you will open the page to debug
- another one where you can open `chrome://inspect` and find the first instance.

Comment: This might work for debugging Chrome on Android, but didn't work for me on my computer. I went to chrome://inspect/#pages, found the tab, hit inspect, but dev tools still closed when the window closed.

Answer (score 1):

Just press F8 before closing and pause, then add breakpoints.

Comment: The only one that worked with a Chrome-based browser popup authn window (while testing new connection in a custom connector for PowerAutomate). In a fast sequence, press Ctrl+Shift+I (to load Developer Tools) then F8 to break the execution. From there, try the other recommendations.