# Debugging a Chrome instance with "remote-debugging-port" flag

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I'm trying to follow the steps described under **Basics: Using DevTools as protocol client** on https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/. I launch two Chrome instances with `google-chrome --remote-debugger-port=9222`
 and `google-chrome --user-data-dir=/home/whatever/Desktop/chrome/`. After that, I navigate to `http://127.0.0.1:9222/` but I get a "This site can’t be reached" error page.

If instead of this I launch Chrome with `google-chrome --headless --remote-debugging-port=9222`, when I navigate to `http://127.0.0.1:9222/` I can see "Inspectable WebContents" and a link to a blank page .

Anyone has an idea on why the `remote-debugging-port` flag is only working with a headless instance? From what i can understand it should work both ways.

Note: What I'm attempting is to be able to use Puppeteer on a Chorme instance using the `connect` method (https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#puppeteerconnectoptions).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I managed to get it to work by launching chrome as following: `google-chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir=/home/whatever/Desktop/chrome/`

Comment: I am still having the same issue with this code as well

Answer (score 13):

The issue is `user-data-dir=`.

You can point to your current profile directory, it may cause some problems.
Debugging don't start without this argument.

On windows you can start as:
`C:\>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe " --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir=/temp'`

From new versions, don't look anymore to `http://localhost:9222/`.

The correct way is open a new window and load `chrome://inspect`.
Any debugging instance will be show under devices list.

[image: Chrome://inspect]