# Telegram login widget with django TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'postMessage') with some browsers

Tags: javascript, django, google-chrome, telegram, django-allauth

I'm trying to implement Telegram login widget in my Django website. I'm using django-allauth and the login did work indeed for my test with Firefox browser but it failed to work on mobile devices and Chrome desktop. Authorization dialog just disappear after entering my phone number and confirming the login in Telegram messenger.

I was able to run a debugger for the quickly [disappearing popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11136010/how-do-i-prevent-chrome-developer-tools-from-closing-when-the-current-browser-wi) window and caught this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'postMessage')

[image]

Login page is:

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <script async src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-widget.js?21" data-telegram-login="NameOfTelegrambot" data-size="medium" data-userpic="false" data-auth-url="https://example.com/accounts/telegram/login/"></script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Login works with Firefox browser and I can see:

> Successfully signed in as TelegramUserName.

And user name is shown in the  upper right corner as singed in to "django-classified"

But that doesn't happen in Chrome or in some popular Mobile browsers that I've tested.

There is [docker compose file](https://gitlab.com/uak/django_classified/) to test the setup that can work locally after providing some Telegram Bot token in the `.env` file.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this issue.
After a long debugging process, I found that it only requires configuring the following in the Django configuration file:

```py
SECURE_CROSS_ORIGIN_OPENER_POLICY = "same-origin-allow-popups"
```

This should resolve the issue.

It has been a while since this problem occurred; I'm not sure if it can still help you.
Wishing the next person facing this issue good luck.