# Can I force to keep the chrome tab open via extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

lets say, using something like chrome.tabs.onRemoved - whenever a user would close that specific tab, it would just reopen(chrome.tabs.movec).
Is that possible? If not, why?

I tried it, but failed and I don't understand why - according to the spec it should not close the window.

Comment: Why you do that to harm user experience in general? Could you provide the code what you've done?

Comment: it's not about harming, I just dumbed the question down. I'm trying to create a popup window at user's command detaching a tab . and then I want it to reattach it, if the user (accidentally, or also for purpose) closes it.

Comment: Probably duplicate with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146930/how-to-keep-google-chrome-extension-popup-open