# Keeping chrome extension popup open when opening link in background tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I searched all over and haven't found an answer. I'm developing a Chrome extension and would like to know how to make the popup window stay open if the user chooses to open a link in a new background tab. (For example, clicking on the link while pressing the "ctrl" key.) Currently when I do that, the popup closes even though the user stays on the current tab.

It is different than [How to keep Google Chrome Extension popup open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146930/how-to-keep-google-chrome-extension-popup-open), as that's talking about when the user focuses on a different window, then the popup closes. I'm talking about when the user specifically stays focused on the popup, as in the example given that the user presses "ctrl" while clicking on the link, that the focus stays on current page.

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146930/how-to-keep-google-chrome-extension-popup-open

Comment: Please see the edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
chrome.tabs.create({ url, active: false });
```

From the docs:

> **active** (boolean, optional): Whether the tab should become the active tab in the window. Does not affect whether the window is focused (see windows.update). Defaults to true.

Ref: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/