# Is there any way to avoid the chrome extension popup from fading out when the user clicks anywhere else on page or changes the tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am currently working on developing a chrome extension using AngularJs. I am beginner to this development. I wanted to know if there is any way using which i can avoid the chrome extension popup from getting closed when user clicks anywhere else on webpage or user switches between the tabs. I understand that the extension gets opened only when it gets focused but i needed it to be persistent and not fade out.

Please help!

Comment: don't ever do that its extremely annoying

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep Google Chrome Extension popup open?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146930/how-to-keep-google-chrome-extension-popup-open)

Comment: @madalinivascu, While it might be annoying when inappropriately used, having a panel open which the user can interact with while also interacting with pages/tabs/windows can desirable, or even necessary (when appropriate). It is the case that it is often desired by developers when it is not appropriate. That said, as the linked duplicate explains, a extension popup is not a viable way to accomplish this.